# Undefined Function outside Header Error Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play-games

I am currently linking a static library to my Android Project which contains the functions I want to use, the problem that occurs is when I call a function from the static library in Android Project, and the function definition is in a .cpp file, my build fails. If that function is defined in a header through a class for example, the project compiles and runs.

The .cpp file is compiled with the definition and the project still outputs an error of no definition.

Edit: I noticed a new error message of the function outputting that it's not an ELF object.

Android Project Calls Function from Static Library:

```
Example.h
void example();

Example.cpp
void example()
{
} //Error
```

Example.h

```
class example
{
public:
  void example()
  {

  }//Compiles
}
```

Error:

> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld" -z noexecstack --warn-shared-textrel -z now -z relro --hash-style=both --enable-new-dtags --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -shared -o "Debug\\Android-x86\\x86\\libProject.so" "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/16\crtbegin_so.o" "-LC:\\ProjectFolder\\ProjectFolder\\Debug\\Android-x86\\x86" "-LC:\\ProjectFolder\\ProjectFolder\\StaticLibrary" "-LC:\\ProjectFolder\\ProjectFolder\\StaticLibrary\\Source" -u ANativeActivity_onCreate "-LC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\9.0.9\lib\linux\i386" "-LC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x" "-LC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/16" "-LC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android" "-LC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/lib" "-LC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin/../sysroot/usr/lib" --exclude-libs libgcc.a --exclude-libs libatomic.a -z noexecstack -z relro --build-id=md5 --no-undefined -z now "Debug\\Android-x86\\Main.o" -lEGL -lGLESv2 -landroid -latomic -lStaticLibrary "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\21.4.7075529\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\sysroot\\usr\\lib\\i686-linux-android\\libc++_shared.so" -soname=libProject.so -lc++ -lm -lgcc -ldl -lc -lgcc -ldl "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/16\crtend_so.o"
> 1>C:\ProjectFolder\ProjectFolder\ProjectFolder/Main.cpp(10): error : undefined reference to 'FunctionName()'
> 1>C:\ProjectFolder\ProjectFolder\ProjectFolder/Main.cpp(10): error : clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: Add compilation/linkage errors you get.

Comment: Added the Error Output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried moving all my static library files to a new project and it seems that the previous static library Visual Studio project was corrupted, after moving over to a new clean project everything compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The linker clearly says `undefined reference to 'FunctionName()'`

In other words it can't find the source file with `FunctionName()` implementation. Make sure the file is compiled or implementation is placed in the same namespace with the same name (in this particular case without any namespace).

Comment: The file with the definition is in the same directory as the header file, the problem I am finding is the file with the definition being compiled, but still the error of no definition is being outputted.

Comment: @user12826193 And I'd insist on double check. There're a few reasons for undefined reference. Try to double check it - on of the ways is to change function name.

Comment: I changed the function name, changed the file names, the directory, etc. All .cpp files that define functions from headers result in undefined references in static library.

Comment: @user12826193 are you sure you have those files in static library then? `nm static_library.a` and grep for you function. If not something's wrong with build instructions.

Comment: Can you explain where I input those commands, I am new to the android systems, and yes, the files are in the static library folder which contains the header and .cpp files. I assume you may be correct on the build instruction as I believe it's something to do with that, I will have to investigate further. Edit: I am using Visual Studio also